# Expand and Shrink UIScrollView with animation

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, core-animation, accordion

I am having a `UITableView` inside a scrollview.  So I am trying to do a accordion like component using `UITableView`.  So I need to expand the `UITableView` to add more cell.  In that case I have to increase the height of `UIScrollView` with a animation so that it matches the table animation.

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
    BOOL preventReopen = NO;

    if (row == expandedRowIndex + 1 && expandedRowIndex != -1)
        return nil;

    [tableView beginUpdates];
    if (expandedRowIndex != -1)
    {
        familyTableView.frame = CGRectMake(familyTableView.frame.origin.x, familyTableView.frame.origin.y, familyTableView.frame.size.width, 3*50+22);

        toolsTableView.frame = CGRectMake(toolsTableView.frame.origin.x, familyTableView.frame.origin.y + familyTableView.frame.size.height + 20, toolsTableView.frame.size.width, 4*50+22);

        myAccountTableView.frame = CGRectMake(myAccountTableView.frame.origin.x, toolsTableView.frame.origin.y + toolsTableView.frame.size.height + 20, myAccountTableView.frame.size.width, 2*50+22);

        settingsScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, familyTableView.frame.size.height + toolsTableView.frame.size.height+ myAccountTableView.frame.size.height + 380);
        settingsScrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, familyTableView.frame.size.height + toolsTableView.frame.size.height+ myAccountTableView.frame.size.height + 380, 0);

        NSInteger rowToRemove = expandedRowIndex + 1;

        preventReopen = row == expandedRowIndex;
        if (row > expandedRowIndex)
            row--;
        expandedRowIndex = -1;
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowToRemove inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    }else {
        familyTableView.frame = CGRectMake(familyTableView.frame.origin.x, familyTableView.frame.origin.y, familyTableView.frame.size.width, (3*50+22) + 100);

        toolsTableView.frame = CGRectMake(toolsTableView.frame.origin.x, familyTableView.frame.origin.y + familyTableView.frame.size.height + 20, toolsTableView.frame.size.width, 4*50+22);

        myAccountTableView.frame = CGRectMake(myAccountTableView.frame.origin.x, toolsTableView.frame.origin.y + toolsTableView.frame.size.height + 20, myAccountTableView.frame.size.width, 2*50+22);

        settingsScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, familyTableView.frame.size.height + toolsTableView.frame.size.height+ myAccountTableView.frame.size.height + 380);
        settingsScrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, familyTableView.frame.size.height + toolsTableView.frame.size.height+ myAccountTableView.frame.size.height + 380, 0);
    }
    NSInteger rowToAdd = -1;
    if (!preventReopen)
    {
        rowToAdd = row + 1;
        expandedRowIndex = row;
        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowToAdd inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];

    }
    [tableView endUpdates];

    return nil;
}
```

I am not good at animation.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  What I need is when we do `[tableView beginUpdates]` we have to start animating the resize effect to UIScrollView and it should end when `[tableView endUpdates]` executes.  So the Accordion executes flawlessly.  Thanks in advance for any help..

Comment: So what is your question? What result are you expecting from your code and what are you getting? Do you know that the table view is a scroll view itself, do you really need it to be contained in another scroll view?

Comment: Hai @DavidRönnqvist thanks for your help.. I am adding three tableviews inside one scroll view.  So When I try to expand one table it will go behind another so I am increasing the size of the scroll view also and it is working just fine.  But the problem is the scrollview expands suddenly and the  beginUpdate goes with animation.  So the view looks bad.

Comment: I just know the information that tableview itself a scrollview.  Thank you for the information.

Comment: You know that you can have multiple sections in your table view, right? Having multiple table views after each other sound like you are trying to do sections.

Comment: It is similar to that. But I may have to add some content in-between tables..

Comment: Else I have to do that and add content to the footer for each and every sections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are changing a *view* property (the frame of the scroll view) I would recommend that you use a UIView animation to animate the frame. You may need to tweak the timing slightly to make it look perfect but I believe that the animation is both EaseInEaseOut and takes 0.4 seconds. You would to the animation like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
    // Change all your animatable properties like your frames here...
    yourScrollView.frame = theNewScrollViewFrame;
}];
```

Comment: Hay David thanks for your help.. I finally figured out.  I have given the answer below.  Your answer gave me an heads up.. thank you very much..

Answer (score 1):

I finally fixed it by following code

```
// Start the animation before the begin update and commit it after the end update.        
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];

        [tableView beginUpdates];
<My code which I given in the question>
       [tableView endUpdates];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Hope it helps some one in future..

Comment: Please give me an example.. if that works.  I will change the accepted answer.. sorry if ask so basic question.

Comment: I really meant "change all your frames here"... theNewFrame was just meant as pseudocode for the frame that you calculated. In practice this would be almost all the code between beginUpdates and endUpdates just like you wrote it. This is why I asked. You basically answered the exact same thing that I did but using the older UIView animation API instead of the block API

Comment: Ohh if I put all my code inside the animation block.. it should work right??